# Translating Facebook Open Graph messages?

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-opengraph

I need to implement open graph action in multilingual. I don't find any place in open graph dashboard where i can define translations for my actions. I have set locale for the required area in meta but could find the right way for translation.
Can someone please help me in it's implementation, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Internationalization](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/) documentation, it’s all explained there.
And see also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/internationalization/